# jersey RESTful api replies 415 unsupported media type when using FormDataMultipart

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I am building a RESTful API in java using jersey 2.22.1. I have a resource class where I intend to receive a file which the client will upload through a form. My problem is I keep getting 415 unsupported media type response from the server. And interestingly the client (Postman chrome extension) receives status 0, an error connecting to server when the file was jpg image

There is another method in the resource class made for test purposes and that works just fine. I've googled searched the stackoverflow website, could find similar cases but was not helping my case. All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Resource class

```
package org.sime.seven.managefiles.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.ContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataBodyPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;

@Path("files")
public class UploadResource {

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String test(){
        return "testing 1,2,3";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart formData){
        FormDataBodyPart filePart = formData.getField("file");
        ContentDisposition fileHeader = filePart.getContentDisposition();
        String fileName = fileHeader.getFileName();
        String reply = "File confirmed" + fileName;
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(reply).build();
    }



}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

            <groupId>org.sime.seven</groupId>
            <artifactId>managefiles</artifactId>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>managefiles</name>

            <build>
                <finalName>managefiles</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.1</version>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>

            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                        <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                    <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
                    <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
                </dependency>
                <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
            <properties>
                <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            </properties>
        </project>
```

[resulting jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKzPJ.jpg)

Comment: Did you register the `MutliPartFeature`?

Comment: @peeskillet no I haven't, I didn't know there was more to do. could you tell me how I would go about registering it?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435)

Comment: Thank you. That helped solve the issue. I somehow didn't come across that question in my search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that, as mentioned in the comments, to use the `FormDataMultipart` class from jersey, one needs to register `MultipartFeature`

so I added init param to the web.xml like below

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and it worked just fine.