# error while uploading a file in webservices "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception"

Tags: web-services, file, rest

hi guys I'm having an issue in uploading a file from client using

> restful webservices

the java code is:

```
    @POST  
    @Path("/upload")  
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)  
    public Response uploadFile(  
            @FormParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,  
            @FormParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) 
    {  
        String fileLocation = "e://" + fileDetail.getFileName();  
        //saving file  
        try 
        {  
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));  
            int read = 0;  
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];  
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));  
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) 
            {  
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);  
            }  
            out.flush();  
            out.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
        String output = "File successfully uploaded to : " + fileLocation;  
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();  
    }
```

web.xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.domain.copy</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;  
                         org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my error message is: 
    HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/mimepull/MIMEParsingException
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:253)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:247)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:119)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:797)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:465)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$2.run(IntrospectionModeller.java:253)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.getAllDeclaredMethods(IntrospectionModeller.java:247)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkForNonPublicMethodIssues(IntrospectionModeller.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:119)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:80)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:112)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:109)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:797)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:465)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.18 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.18
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `mimepull` jar. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet added it. but still same error.