# Upload binary data with HTTP PUT with jersey jaxrs-ri-2.01

Tags: upload, jersey, jax-rs, binaryfiles, put

I am using jaxrs-ri-2.01
I would like to get in a parameter the binary data that is sent in the body of my HTTP PUT request.

I have found one annotation that should do the trick :

```
@FormDataParam
```

but it does not seem to be available for the jaxrs-ri-2.01

I would like to know:

1. if there's a way I can do it with this jaxrs-ri version
2. if it's mandatory to change jaxrs-ri version to a more recent one
3. how to use this annotation

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. if there's a way I can do it with this jaxrs-ri version

You need the `jersey-media-multipart`. This has the multipart support. If you are using Maven, add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version> <!-- or whatever version
</dependency>                     you plan to use. -->
```

If you are not using Maven, you can find the download [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart). Scroll down and select the Jersey version you are using. Then click the  <kbd>Download (Jar)</kbd> button to download. You will also need the `mimepull` jar that goes with it. To find it, scroll down and click version button that goes with `mimepull`.

> 2. if it's mandatory to change jaxrs-ri version to a more recent one

Any 2.x version will have the multipart support in a different artifact, as mentioned above.

> 3. how to use this annotation

First you will need to register the `MultiPartFeature`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435) for help. Then just do something like

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response post(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file) {
   ...
}
```

**See Also** (for details and examples):

- [Jersey documentation for Multipart](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart)
- [File upload along with other object in Jersey restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27609569/2587435)

Comment: I'm on it, I downloaded jersey-media-multipart-2.0.1.jar and mimepull-1.8.jar. I added them to my project. I also added the @ Consumes and @ FormDataParam parameter. But now I have an error, both at launch of Tomcat and when sending the PUT request: WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response

Comment: Did you register the `MultiPartFeature`?

Comment: If you mean that, the **@ Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)** is there and I also added **import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;** and also **import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;** . I see no errors in the "Problems" tab of Eclipse after compilation.

Comment: Please read the link I provided about registering the feature

Comment: Indeed, I missed that link. So I added in my web.xml **<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>** and now, no more errors, I need to test further, but I would say it's OK now.

Comment: Thanks again **peeskillet** I think it's the second time you helped me successfully!