# HTTP Error 415 Unsupported media type

Tags: upload, jersey, binaryfiles, put, http-status-code-415

I am still on the same problem as:
[Upload binary data with HTTP PUT with jersey jaxrs-ri-2.01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956085/upload-binary-data-with-http-put-with-jersey-jaxrs-ri-2-01/33957438?noredirect=1#comment55676414_33957438)

But I am one step further. Now I am testing my data upload with this tool:
[I'm Only Resting](http://www.swensensoftware.com/im-only-resting)

The problem, and I don't know if it's a client or a server problem is that when I'm testing, I get **HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type**

In the client:

- I have checked the **PUT** method
- In the body I have put **one blank line (return)** and in the second line i wrote **test**

In the server, It was working until I added this parameter

```
 @FormDataParam("file") InputStream pBodyDataStream
```

and this code:

```
    try {
        OutputStream lOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("F:/test.bin"));

        int read = 0;

        byte[] bytes = new byte[fragmentSize];

        while ((read = pBodyDataStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            lOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        lOutputStream.close();
        pBodyDataStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // fragment reception error

        // HTTP 500 error
        lOutput = xmlError("Upload error while transferring fragment");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(lOutput).build();
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the test tool with the parameters:

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Here is the cURL investigation:**

The command line:

```
curl -v -H "application/octet-stream" -K params_curl.txt
```

The cURL parameters file:

```
url = "localhost:8080/ServeurWS/softplus/biens/arts/2345412/images?user=wow&pass=wow&taille=100&numfrag=1&taillefrag=10&md5=d6aa97d33d459ea3670056e737c99a3d&md6=5da8aa7126701c9840f99f8e9fa54976"
request="PUT"
upload-file="f:/vcredist.bmp"
output = "output.html"
user-agent = "superagent/1.0"
```

The headers I see, thanks to the **-v** option:

```
C:\Users\Dev\Desktop>curl -v -I -H "application/octet-stream" -K params_curl.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> PUT /ServeurWS/softplus/biens/arts/2345412/images?user=wow&pass=wow&taille=100&numfrag=1&taillefrag=10&md5=d6aa97d33d459ea3670056e737c99a3d&md6=5da8aa7126701
c9840f99f8e9fa54976 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: superagent/1.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 5686
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [5686 bytes data]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 415 Type de Support Non Supporté
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1108
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 13:56:07 GMT
<
{ [1108 bytes data]
100  6794  100  1108  100  5686  11080  56860 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 63177
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

The **output.html** file:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 415 Type de Support Non Supporté
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1108
Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 13:56:07 GMT

<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.44 - Rapport d'erreur</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>Etat HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Rapport d'Ã©tat</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Unsupported Media Type</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>Le serveur a refusÃ© cette requÃªte car l'entitÃ© de requÃªte est dans un format non supportÃ© par la ressource demandÃ©e avec la mÃ©thode spÃ©cifiÃ©e.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.44</h3></body></html>
```

And there is no error in the Eclipse console...

Comment: I have never used that tool, but can you post a screen shot of how you make the request. Also are you sure it supports multipart? If not, you may want to test with a different client (i.e. cURL-a command line client, or Postman-a Chrome plugin)

Comment: I'm installing Postman right now.

Comment: Maybe cURL is a better choice...

Comment: cURL is my favorite client of all time. I don't know what I'd do without it :-)

Comment: Okay...cURL is a good tool but... I still get my HTTP 415 error.

Comment: What's the command you're using?

Comment: I just edited the question for more information.

Comment: Use `curl -v -X PUT -F "file=test text" <url>`. The `-F` is used for each body part, and automatically sets the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data`, which is what you need. You can replace `"file=test text"` with `"file=@<path-to_file>"`

Comment: it works with that command line! thank you again **peeskillet**!