# Reading JSON from REST API in PHP - No data

Tags: php, rest, curl

Trying to figure out how to call a REST API with a PHP script and return the data from the JSON response.  I think I have a pretty decent script written, but I must be missing something because no matter what I try, I can't get any data to show from the response.

Here is the script so far:

```
     <?php 

function LoginAPI() {

    $login_url = 'https://blah blah blah blah';
    $curl = curl_init($login_url);
    $curl_post_data = array(
            'clientName' => '**********',
            'userName' => '*********',
            'password' => '**********'
    );

    $curl_headers = array(
            'Host' => '***********',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_headers);

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);

    echo 'Trying to output' . '<br>';
    //var_export($decoded); //NULL
    //var_dump(json_decode($curl_response)); //blank
    //print_r($decoded); //BLANK
    //echo $decoded; //BLANK
}

    LoginAPI();

    ?>
```

The problem is at the end of the above code in the last 4 commented lines.  These are all the methods I have tried to simply display the contents of $decoded, and it either says "NULL" or just displays a blank page, as indicated above.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

(Yes, I have found a LOT of other posts addressing similar issues, but not the same.  Being such a noob, I'm not certain how to adapt the suggestions in other posts to my situation.)

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Look at the raw response before cramming into `json_decode()`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I don't know what error logs you are referring to.  The script above is literally the entirety of my code.

Comment: @PaulCrovella - how do I "look" at "json_last_error_msg and then $curl_response"?  I am a total newbie to REST API and only know enough PHP to be dangerous

Comment: @Sammitch - How do I look at the raw response?

Comment: Your server has error logs and they will help you to solve issues @LegalEagle

Comment: I only have access to cPanel as this is a shared hosting plan.   I went into (what I believe to be) the error logs and found this:  [Tue Jul 31 13:16:03 2018] [error] [client 204.42.19.82] File does not exist: /home/eaglerec/public_html/404.shtml
[Tue Jul 31 13:16:03 2018] [error] [client 204.42.19.82] File does not exist: /home/eaglerec/public_html/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 31 13:15:53 2018] [error] [client 204.42.19.82] File does not exist: /home/eaglerec/public_html/401.shtml

Comment: I have no idea why it was trying to pull those files.  I have no idea what these errors mean in relation to what I'm trying to accomplish, and I don't know what my next steps should be.  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just before curl_close($curl) I added:   echo $curl_response and got this:       HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2018 17:27:39 GMT Content-Length: 0 Connection: close

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do you know what any of the above error messages would indicate? I am hoping to at least find a direction so I can research further.  Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your URL to the resource is wrong and the errors mean the file you were looking for is not found. Read this about the unsupported media type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34016960/http-error-415-unsupported-media-type