# Jax-Rs parameters to retrieve Multipart

Tags: image, jersey, jax-rs, retrofit

Which parameters would be needed to handle Multipart Retrofit String and RequestBody of an image (file) Post request and which annotations?

**Jax-Rs:**

```
@POST
@Path("/user/image")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response addUserImage(?, ?) {}
```

**Retrofit 2.0:**

```
@Multipart
@POST("user/image")
Call<User> addUserImage(@Part("user") String userId, @Part("image") RequestBody image);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a file you can use `File`, `InputStream`, or `byte[]`. For plain text, just use a String. You will also need to annotate the parameter with `@FormDataParam("<value>")`, with the value being the name of the part.

```
@POST
@Path("/user/image")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response addUserImage(@FormDataParam("image") InputStream image,
                             @FormDataParam("image") FormDataContentDisposition imageDetail,
                             @FormDataParam("user") String user) {   
}
```

You will need to make sure you have the multipart support dependency. Not sure which Jersey version you are using, but here is for both

Jersey 2.x

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Jersey 1.x

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey1.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

With Jersey 1.x, it should work out the box without any further configuration. For 2.x, you will need to register the `MultiPartFeature`. For help with that, please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435)