# HTTP status 415 when using Alamofire multipart upload

Tags: swift, rest, jersey, alamofire

I'm trying to get an image uploaded to a RESTful web api and I'm getting a HTTP status 415 (unsupported media type). The strange thing is I did have it working the other day and i'm not to sure what i've changed to make it stop accepting the POST request.

My swift code:

```
func uploadImage(image: UIImage, userId: String, completion: () -> Void) {
    parameters["userId"] = userId

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 70)
    let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents(myUrl, parameters: parameters, imageData: imageData!)

    Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
            if let result = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, String>{
                print("have a result from uploading!")
                print(result)
                if let result = result["success"] {
                    if (result == "true") {
                       completion()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}


func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, String>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {


    // create url request to send
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data"
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add image
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData(imageData)

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}
```

And here is what my Jersey Rest service accepts for that url:

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadImage")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String uploadImage(FormDataMultiPart form) throws IOException
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Its driving me crazy trying to figure out what is going wrong, any help is muchly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the server?

Comment: Did you [register the MultiPartFeature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435)?

Comment: @peeskillet not getting anything come through on the server, only reason i knew what error i was getting was because i used .ResponseString to print out the result

Comment: @peeskillet
I possibly don't have the init in my web.xml for the multipart, will check when i'm home

Comment: Yeah, not register it _would_ cause the 415 in this case, as without the registration , there is no provider to handle multipart

Comment: I am getting same error. Let me know what to do ?