# org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I'm developing **spring boot microservices** example from the link: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-creating. In this project I simply updated the parent dependency to its latest version and other code files are unchanged. I faced the following error when I click **http://localhost:8080/order?idCustomer=2&idProduct=3&amount=4**

```
2016-09-09 11:46:20.888 ERROR 14152 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : StandardWrapper.Throwable

org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public java.util.List br.com.alexandreesl.handson.rest.ProductRest.getProducts() and public java.util.List br.com.alexandreesl.handson.rest.CustomerRest.getCustomers() at matching regular expression /. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@14c14bf']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255) ~[jersey-common-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

the updated **pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Named
    static class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
        public JerseyConfig() {
            this.packages("br.com.alexandreesl.handson.rest");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
public class Order {
    private long id;
    private long amount;
    private Date dateOrder;
    private Customer customer;
    private Product product;
    // setters and getters
}
```

**OrderRest.java**

```
@Named
@Path("/")
public class OrderRest {
    private long id = 1;

    @Inject
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GET
    @Path("order")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Order submitOrder(@QueryParam("idCustomer") long idCustomer,
            @QueryParam("idProduct") long idProduct,
            @QueryParam("amount") long amount) {

        Customer customer = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/customer?id={id}", Customer.class, idCustomer);
        Product product = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/product?id={id}", Product.class,idProduct);

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setCustomer(customer);
        order.setProduct(product);
        order.setId(id);
        order.setAmount(amount);
        order.setDateOrder(new Date());
        id++;
        return order;
    }
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
public class Customer {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    // setters and getters
}
```

**CustomerRest.java**

```
@Named
@Path("/")
public class CustomerRest {
    private static List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    static {
        Customer customer1 = new Customer();
        customer1.setId(1);
        customer1.setNome("Customer 1");
        customer1.setEmail("customer1@gmail.com");

        Customer customer2 = new Customer();
        customer2.setId(2);
        customer2.setNome("Customer 2");
        customer2.setEmail("Customer2@gmail.com");

        Customer customer3 = new Customer();
        customer3.setId(3);
        customer3.setNome("Customer 3");
        customer3.setEmail("Customer3@gmail.com");

        Customer customer4 = new Customer();
        customer4.setId(4);
        customer4.setNome("Customer 4");
        customer4.setEmail("Customer4@gmail.com");

        Customer customer5 = new Customer();
        customer5.setId(5);
        customer5.setNome("Customer 5");
        customer5.setEmail("Customer5@gmail.com");

        customers.add(customer1);
        customers.add(customer2);
        customers.add(customer3);
        customers.add(customer4);
        customers.add(customer5);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("customer")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Customer getCustomer(@QueryParam("id") long id) {
        Customer cli = null;
        for (Customer c : customers) {
            if (c.getId() == id)
                cli = c;
        }
        return cli;
    }
}
```

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {
    private long id;
    private String sku;
    private String description;
    // setters and getters
}
```

**ProductRest.java**

```
@Named
@Path("/")
public class ProductRest {
    private static List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    static {
        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.setId(1);
        product1.setSku("abcd1");
        product1.setDescription("Product1");
        Product product2 = new Product();
        product2.setId(2);
        product2.setSku("abcd2");
        product2.setDescription("Product2");
        Product product3 = new Product();
        product3.setId(3);
        product3.setSku("abcd3");
        product3.setDescription("Product3");
        Product product4 = new Product();
        product4.setId(4);
        product4.setSku("abcd4");
        product4.setDescription("Product4");
        products.add(product1);
        products.add(product2);
        products.add(product3);
        products.add(product4);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("product")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Product getProduct(@QueryParam("id") long id) {
        Product prod = null;
        for (Product p : products) {
            if (p.getId() == id)
                prod = p;
        }
        return prod;
    }
}
```

Please guide on this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MULTIPART\_FORM\_DATA: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653012/multipart-form-data-no-injection-source-found-for-a-parameter-of-type-public-ja)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. you need to make some changes in mapping request URL. I wonder how code in the block is working without error.

As per my understanding one possible cause is that you have two or more applicable mappings for that URL call. `CustomerRest.java` and `ProductRest.java` both were mapped to `/`.

```
@Path("/")
```

And

```
@Path("/")
```

The `Jersey` have no way of telling what method is actually supposed to be called and gives this error.

You need to correct following files:
**OrderRest.java**

```
@Named
@Path("/")
public class OrderRest {
    private long id = 1;

    @Inject
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GET
    @Path("order")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Order submitOrder(@QueryParam("idCustomer") long idCustomer,
            @QueryParam("idProduct") long idProduct,
            @QueryParam("amount") long amount) {

        Customer customer = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/customer/getCustomer?id={id}", Customer.class, idCustomer);
        Product product = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/product/getProduct?id={id}", Product.class,idProduct);

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setCustomer(customer);
        order.setProduct(product);
        order.setId(id);
        order.setAmount(amount);
        order.setOrderDate(new Date());
        id++;
        return order;
    }
}
```

In **CustomerRest.java** - use this

```
@GET
    @Path("/getCustomer")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Customer getCustomer(@QueryParam("id") long id) {
        Customer cli = null;
        for (Customer c : customers) {
            if (c.getId() == id)
                cli = c;
        }
        return cli;
    }
```

In **ProductRest** - use this

```
@GET
    @Path("/getProduct")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Product getProduct(@QueryParam("id") long id) {
        Product prod = null;
        for (Product p : products) {
            if (p.getId() == id)
                prod = p;
        }
        return prod;
    }
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this also happens sometimes when we accidentially use the `@QueryParam` instead of `@FormParam` or vice versa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).