# MULTIPART_FORM_DATA: No injection source found for a parameter of type Response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to get a file upload working for JAX-RS using multipart/form-data. When I try to start the server it gives me this error:

```
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
com.pododdle.resources.UploadResource.uploadAudio(int,int,java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition)
    at index 2.;source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[text/html], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class 
com.pododdle.resources.UploadResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@29d4c93f]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response 
com.pododdle.resources.UploadResource.uploadAudio(int,int,java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition), parameters=[Parameter [type=int, source=auction_id, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=int, source=category_id, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.mimepull</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

The version of the mimepull that works with version 2.22.1 of jersey i get from from here: https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart/2.22.1

Is there something I am missing, or haven't configured properly? Am a novice at this, so go easy on me... :)

Comment: Have your registered the `MultipartFeature` in your `ResourceConfig` class? Something like `register(MultipartFeature.class);`.

Comment: Hi Cassio, I don't have a resourceconfig class. Do I need one, and what does it do?

Comment: You could have one. But you also could register this feature in the `web.xml`.

Comment: Why would I have to register this class - why is just having the jar on the classpath not sufficient?

Comment: The `web.xml` deployment descriptor is located under the `WEB-INF` directory.

Comment: Just having the `MultiparFeature` class on the classpath is not enough. Except for a few extensions features, Jersey 2.x does not implicitly register any extension features from the modules available on the classpath. Users are expected to explicitly register them.

Comment: cheers cassio - that looks like it worked - thanks a million

Comment: This [answer provided by peeskillet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/1426227) is really insightful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you don't have a [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html), try registering the [`MultiparFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html) in the `web.xml` deployment descriptor:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

If you have more provider class names in the `<param-value>`, use `,` to separate them.