# Java/Jersey - creating own injection resolver with ParamInjectionResolver - strange behavior

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jersey, hk2

I am trying to create an injection resolver. I have a data class:

```
public class MyData {
    ...
}
```

I have the following annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MyDataInject {
}
```

My injection resolver looks like this:

```
public class MyDataInjectionResolver extends ParamInjectionResolver<MyDataInject> {
    public MyDataInjectionResolver () {
        super(MyDataValueFactoryProvider.class);
    }

    @Singleton
    public static class MyDataValueFactoryProvider extends AbstractValueFactoryProvider {
        @Inject
        public MyDataValueFactoryProvider(MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider provider, ServiceLocator locator) {
            super(provider, locator, Parameter.Source.UNKNOWN);
        }

        @Override
        protected Factory<?> createValueFactory(Parameter parameter) {
            System.out.println(parameter.getRawType());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parameter.getAnnotations()));
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println();

            ... create factory and return ...
        }
    }
}
```

I am binding as following:

```
bind(MyDataValueFactoryProvider.class).to(ValueFactoryProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
bind(MyDataInjectionResolver.class).to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<MyDataInject>>() {}).in(Singleton.class);
```

I left the implementation of the actual factory out for brevity. Everything works fine, but I am noticing some behavior which I cannot explain. I am testing with the following JAX-RS resource:

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {
    @GET
    public Response test(@MyDataInject @Valid MyData data) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Hello world!").build();
    }
}
```

- The first thing I notice is that `MyDataValueFactoryProvider.createValueFactory` is called twice during start-up. Why is that? This smells like some error. The good thing is that the factory is only accessed once when a client does a request.
- Another observation is that if I remove the `@MyDataInject` annotation in the resource as below (*), `MyDataValueFactoryProvider.createValueFactory` is still getting called. Why is that? This is odd, since it should be bound to only `@MyDataInject`? (**update**) It is even called when the parameter is not of class `MyData`, see second variant below.

(*) Resource without `@MyDataInject` annotation:

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {
    @GET
    public Response test(/*@MyDataInject*/ @Valid MyData data) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Hello world!").build();
    }
}
```

Another variant:

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {
    @GET
    public Response test(@Valid SomeOtherClass data) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Hello world!").build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On startup, Jersey builds an internal model of all the resources. Jersey uses this model to process requests. Part of that model consists of all the resource methods and all of its parameters. To take it even further, Jersey will also validate the model to make sure it is a valid model. Something invalid in the model may cause Jersey not to be able to process that model during runtime. So this validation is there to protect us.

That being said, part of the validation process is to validate the method parameters. There are rules that govern what we can have as parameters. For example, a `@QueryParam` parameters must meet one of the requirements mentioned here in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html):

1. Be a primitive type
2. Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument
3. Have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`)
4. Have a registered implementation of `ParamConverterProvider` JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a `ParamConverter` instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.
5. Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 2, 3 or 4 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

Here's something you can try out. Add a `@QueryParam` using the following arbitrary class

```
public class Dummy {
  public String value;
}

@GET
public Response get(@QueryParam("dummy") Dummy dummy) {}
```

Notice that the `Dummy` class doesn't meet any of the requirements listed above. When you run the application, you should get an exception on startup, causing the application to fail. The exception will be something like

```
ModelValidationException: No injection source for parameter ...
```

This means that the validation of the model failed because Jersey has no idea how to create the `Dummy` instance from the query param, as it doesn't follow the rules of what is allowed.

Ok. so how is this all related to your question? Well, all parameter injection requires a `ValueFactoryProvider` to be able to provide a value for it. If there isn't one, then the parameter will not be able to be created at runtime. So Jersey validates the parameters by checking for the existence of a `ValueFactoryProvider` that returns a `Factory`. The method that Jersey calls to obtain the `Factory` at runtime, is the one you mentioned: `createValueFactory`.

Now keep in mind that when we implement the `createValueFactory`, we can either return a `Factory` or we can return null. How we should implement it, is the check to `Parameter` argument to see if we can handle that parameter. For instance

```
protected Factory<?> createValueFactory(Parameter parameter) {
   if (parameter.getRawType() == Dummy.class
       && parameter.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnoation.class)) {
     return new MyFactory();
   }
   return null;
}
```

So here we are telling Jersey what this `ValueFactoryProvider` can handle. In this case we can handle parameters of type `Dummy` and if the parameter is annotated with `@MyAnnotation`.

So what happens during startup validation, for each parameter, Jersey will traverse each `ValueFactoryProvider` registered to see if there is one that can handle that parameter. The only way it can know is if it calls the `createValueFactory` method. If there is one that returns a `Factory`, then it is a success. If all the `ValueFactoryProvider`s are traversed and they all return null, then the model is not valid and we will get the model validation exception. It should be noted that there are a bunch of internal `ValueFactoryProvider`s for parameter annotated with annotations like `@QueryParam`, `@PathParam`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. I get that now. But why is Jersey asking my `MyDataValueFactoryProvider` if it can provide a non-null factory for `SomeOtherclass` or `MyData without @MyDataInject`, while that provider is only bound to `MyDataInject` via `bind(MyDataInjectionResolver.class).to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<MyDataInject>>() {}).in(Singleton.class)`? For `SomeOtherClass` or `MyData without @MyDataInject`, he should know in advance that that provider is not applicable?

Comment: Injection resolver isn't used for parameter injection with Jersey resource methods. The classes you are using, i.e. `ParamInjectionResolver`, `AbstractValueFactoryProvider`, these are just helper DRY classes Jersey used for param injection. The params like `@PathParam` and `@QueryParam` can also be injected into fields and constructors. That's when the injection resolver is used. So the combination of those two helper classes combine to allow for injection everywhere. But all that is needed for parameter injection is the `ValueFactoryProvider`

Comment: `AbstractValueFactoryProvider` is also just an abstract helper class that partially implements `ValueFactoryProvider`. You can try to implement your own `ValueFactoryProvider`. Just that on interface. And you should see that will will work just for parameter injections.

Comment: AH, got it now. I thought that the injection was used everywhere. I didn't get it that HK-2 is only doing it's job for constructor, fields, ... THANKS

Comment: Yea it's kinda complex. I had to do a lot of digging into source code to fully understand it :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have been doing the last days :). Thanks again!