# OffsetDateTime yielding "No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.response" in GET method

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, swagger

I have the following `GET` REST method:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import com.product.rest.api.TransactionsApi;
import com.product.rest.model.Transaction;

@Path("/transactions")

@Api(description = "the transactions API")
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public class TransactionsApiImpl extends TransactionsApi {

    @GET

    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    @ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "Get all transactions", response =     Transaction.class, responseContainer = "List", tags = {})
    @ApiResponses(
        value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response =     Transaction.class, responseContainer = "List"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request", response =     Transaction.class, responseContainer = "List"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found", response =     Transaction.class, responseContainer = "List"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error",     response = Transaction.class, responseContainer = "List") })
    @Override
    public Response transactionsGet(
        @HeaderParam("tok") String tok,
        @QueryParam("param1") Integer param1,
        @QueryParam("param2") String param2,
        @QueryParam("param3") OffsetDateTime param3,
        @QueryParam("param4") OffsetDateTime param4,
        @QueryParam("param5") Integer param5,
        @QueryParam("param6") Integer param6,
        @QueryParam("param7") String param7) {
        return Response.ok().entity("Success!").build();
    }
```

The `TransactionsApi` is a generated implementation using Swagger Codegen, as is the `Transaction` model class. I have several other functions in this class, but whenever I leave the `GET /transactions` function uncommented, I receive the following error:

```
WARN [Thread-1] (ContextHandler.java:2175) - unavailable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.

[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response     
com.product.rest.impl.v1.TransactionsApiImpl.transactionsGet(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String,java.time.OffsetDateTime,java.time.OffsetDateTime,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String) at index 3.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.product.rest.impl.v1.TransactionsApiImpl, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@7df78e88]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
```

All other similar questions I have found had to do with `MultiPart Data` and file uploading, whereas I am making a simple `GET` request. Other functions that also use the `javax.ws.rs.code.Response` class do not have this issue and the server starts normally.

I have noticed that the problem happens whenever the `OffsetDateTime` class is in the parameters (i.e. `param3` and `param4`), but I have been unable to find out why. Moreover, `OffsetDateTime` was chosen by Swagger Codegen and I am reluctant to change it seeing how I will have to change every derived file afterwards whenever I regenerate my sources.

Has anyone had this issue before with REST services and `OffsetDateTime`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> All other similar questions I have found had to do with MultiPart Data and file uploading

It's related. The error is a general error you get when Jersey can't validate the resource model. Part of the resource model is the method parameters. Jersey has a system for knowing which parameters it will be able to process and which ones it won't. In your case, it doesn't know how to process the `OffsetDateTime`.

There are a set of rules that you need to follow in order to able to use non basic types as [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html)s (and all other `@XxxParams` such as `@PathParam` and `@FormParam`, etc.):

1. Be a primitive type
2. Have a constructor that accepts a single `String` argument
3. Have a static method named `valueOf` or `fromString` that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, `Integer.valueOf(String)`)
4. Have a registered implementation of `ParamConverterProvider` JAX-RS extension SPI that returns a `ParamConverter` instance capable of a "from string" conversion for the type.
5. Be `List<T>`, `Set<T>` or `SortedSet<T>`, where `T` satisfies 2, 3 or 4 above. The resulting collection is read-only.

So in this case of `OffsetDateTime`, going down the list; it's not a primitive; it doesn't have a String constructor; it doesn't have a static `valueOf` or `fromString`

So basically, the only option left is to implement a `ParamConverter/ParamConverterProvider` for it. The basic set up looks like

```
@Provider
public class OffsetDateTimeProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> clazz, Type type, Annotation[] annotations) {
        if (clazz.getName().equals(OffsetDateTime.class.getName())) {

            return new ParamConverter<T>() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public T fromString(String value) {
                    OffsetDateTime time = ...
                    return (T) time;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString(T time) {
                    return ...;
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Jersey will pass you the String value of the query parameter, and it's your job to to create it and return it.

Then just register the `OffsetDateTimeProvider` with the application. If you're using package scanning, it should be picked up and registered automatically from the `@Provider` annotation.

I don't use Swagger, so I don't know if they already provide something like this already implemented, but it seems odd that they would generate this for you, and not have a way to make it work. I know Jersey 3 will have Java 8 support out the box, but who know when the heck that's gonna be released.

Comment: N.B. That the question and answer relate to Jersey 2 (JAX-RS 2). `ParamConverter` and `ParamConverterProvider` are **not** available in Jersey 1, if for some reason you are using Jersey 1 and cannot upgrade.