# LocalDateTime being set to Null in PUT Request to JAX-RS Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, java-time

I am trying to pass LocalDateTime in the request param of a method but it always logs null. Please help me figure out what I did wrong here:

```
@Path("/book/workOrderId/{workOrderId}")
@PUT
    public Response bookWorkOrder(@Context HttpHeaders headers, @PathParam("countryCode") String countryCode,
            @PathParam("workOrderId") int workOrderId,
            @QueryParam("reasonId") int reasonId,
            @RequestParam(value = "dateTime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")  LocalDateTime dateTime

    ) throws CDException {
    
        logger.debug("dateTime outside if::" + dateTime);
        return Response.ok(true).build();
}
```

Output:

```
22:32:27.659 [http-nio-8300-exec-2] DEBUG c.c.t.i.e.v.impl.WorkorderController - dateTime outside if::null
```

Comment: You are using JAX-RS not Spring MVC thus the `@RequestParam` nor the `@DateTimeFormat` will work as those are for Spring MVC not JAX-RS.

Comment: so how do we pass localDateTime here? @M.Deinum

Comment: Depends on how you submit it? Is it part of the ULR (`@PathParam`) if it is a parameter use `@QueryParam` and if it is part of the form use `@FormParam`. So it depends on how you submit the data.

Comment: i want to pass it as a `@QueryParam` but how do we pass local datetime expression in it. dateTime=2020-10-08T14:00:00 in endpoint isn't working using `@QueryParam("bookingTime") LocalDateTime bookingTime`  @M. Deinum

Comment: No idea. Not sure how JAX-RS is supporting the `javax.time` stuff (hence the change in your title and added tags so that someone who might know can answer it).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39850842/2587435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
@PUT
    public Response bookWorkOrder(@Context HttpHeaders headers, @PathParam("countryCode") String countryCode,
            @PathParam("workOrderId") int workOrderId, @QueryParam("bookingTime") String bookingTime,
            @QueryParam("reasonId") int reasonId) throws CDException {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(bookingTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
        logger.debug("bookingTime:: {}", bookingTime);
return Response.ok(true).build();

}
```