# Getting ModelValidation Exception when using MultipartFormData

Tags: jersey, multipartform-data

```
The service Code looks like below. I have defined @PATH in main class.

@POST
    @Timed
    @Produces(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @ResponseStatusOverride(httpStatus = 202)
    public MetaLinks CreateEdmUpload(@ApiParam(hidden = true) @Auth User user,
                                     @FormDataParam("importInput") FormDataBodyPart jsonPart,
                                     @FormDataParam("file") InputStream mdfStream,
                                     @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition cdh)

            throws ApiException {

        jsonPart.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        ImportInput importInput = jsonPart.getValueAs(ImportInput.class);
```

I have the following dependency in POM

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

AND I am registering the class as well in my client request but when i start the JAVA application to try to POST i get the following error

alidation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public com.rm

What could be wrong.. Can someone please suggest

Comment: Did you [register the MultiPartFeature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes registering multipartFeature solved the problem.