# Jersey restful web service - File upload with multiple object

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I'm new to web service and I'm developing a document management system and trying to save the file and multiple object using Jersey restful web service.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sasianet.dmsservice.data.dao.UserDocumentDao; 
import com.sasianet.dmsservice.data.entity.UserDocument; 
import com.sasianet.dmsservice.data.entity.UserDocumentAttachment;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/userDocument")
public class UserDocumentService {

    @GET 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<UserDocument> findAll(){
        List<UserDocument> userDocuments = null;
        try{ 
            UserDocumentDao udo = new UserDocumentDao();
            userDocuments = udo.findAll(); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userDocuments;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post/test")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response uploadFileWithData(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition cdh,
            @FormDataParam("userDoc") UserDocument userDocument,
            @FormDataParam("attachment") UserDocumentAttachment userDocumentAttachment) throws Exception{

        Image img = ImageIO.read(fileInputStream);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        System.out.println(cdh.getName());
        System.out.println(userDocument.getDescription());
        System.out.println(userDocumentAttachment.getAttachmentName());

        return Response.ok("Cool Tools!").build();
    }   
}
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" metadata-complete="true" version="3.0">
    <display-name>DMSService</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sasianet.dmsservice, com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json,com.jersey.jaxb</param-value>
        </init-param>  
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jersey.media.type.mappings</param-name>
        <param-value>json : application/json, xml : application/xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 

</web-app>
```

Once run this service,  I faced the following error

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.sasianet.dmsservice.service.UserDocumentService.uploadFileWithData(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition,com.sasianet.dmsservice.data.entity.UserDocument) throws java.lang.Exception at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.sasianet.dmsservice.service.UserDocumentService, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@53d69bbb]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.sasianet.dmsservice.service.UserDocumentService.uploadFileWithData(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition,com.sasianet.dmsservice.data.entity.UserDocument) throws java.lang.Exception, parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class com.sasianet.dmsservice.data.entity.UserDocument, source=emp, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}', [WARNING] A resource, Resource{"/file", 0 child resources, 0 resource methods, 0 sub-resource locator, 0 method handler classes, 0 method handler instances}, with path "/file" is empty. It has no resource (or sub resource) methods neither sub resource locators defined.; source='Resource{"/file", 0 child resources, 0 resource methods, 0 sub-resource locator, 0 method handler classes, 0 method handler instances}']
```

Project libraries are

[image]

So, I cant find any solution to this and is there any different way to upload file with multiple object with one rest call.

Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're using the wrong version multipart dependency. Anytime you see `com.sun.jersey` in the package, that is for Jersey 1.x, and you should not use it for a 2.x project. You will need to switch versions and then register the `MultiPartFeature`. For more information, see [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA: No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435)
2. Unless the client is able to set the `Content-Type` for each body part (some clients can't), you will need to tweak the method a little bit, in order to get the result an object. For example

   ```
   public Response post(@FormDataParam("doc") FormDataBodyPart docpart) {
       docpart.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
       UserDocument doc = docpart.getValueAs(UserDocument.class);
   }
   ```

   For the `InputStream` parameter, you don't need to do this. For more detail, see [File upload along with other object in Jersey restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435)

Comment: FormDataContentDisposition

Comment: Got it. Another thing... I want to send a file + 3 object + one List.How to do that?