# Error using Spring @RequestHeader: No injection source found for a parameter

Tags: java, spring

I am exposing a rest end point using Spring with a request header.
Here is the method definition:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;

    public User createUser(@RequestHeader("system_id") String system_id, User userRequest) throws Exception
```

However when I use postman to send request I receive:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public User com.java.api.createUser
```

Any ideas on what I am missing? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

When I have either the system_id or userRequest as the only parameter it works. When they are both included in the parameters they throw the error.

Comment: make it
`public User createUser(@RequestHeader("system_id") String system_id,@RequestBody  User userRequest)`

Comment: Hey I tried that solution but no luck :(

Comment: could this be a dependency issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/3892213

Comment: This does not seem to be the issue as my dependencies are up to date...

Comment: can you try making `User userRequest` -> `@RequestBodyString userRequest`.

Comment: I have the same error when using Spring BindingResult，maybe jersey cannot recognize some class about Spring.