# @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream ...getting org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException

Tags: java, jersey, postman, media-type

I am using jersy and postman. I am getting following error while sending text file as upload file through postman to my web service method.

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [Jersey Web Application]
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response

webservice method in short:
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public Response method(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream
            ,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
            )
```

and I am using jersy org.glassfish.jersey 2.22.1

Please can you suggest what is the solution here and exactly which dependent files version are required.

exception in details:
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Root Cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.lang.Exception at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=MethodHandler{handlerClass=class Resource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@2dc2b33b]}, handlingMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) throws java.lang.Exception, parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:426)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:161)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:286)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:283)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:298)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Comment: You may have the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653012/multipart-form-data-no-injection-source-found-for-a-parameter-of-type-public-ja). The jersey-server dependencies are [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.22.1).

Comment: thanks!!. I have done the same changes as suggested in your mentioned link but still getting the same exception. I am using tomcat 9. is any server related compatibility issue?

Comment: Could you please share the exception you got? With the "Caused by" parts if possible. You can check the linked questions too on the link I shared with you.

Comment: Hi, I have debug it and found that it is causing problem at @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream
   ,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail

Comment: What changes did you make? Can you post exactly what you did? And yes, please also post the _complete_ stack trace.

Comment: Hi,now I have added full stack trace in my question. thanks!!

Comment: If use jersy1.0 and add the jersey-media-multipart jar

Comment: <init-param>
             <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
             <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>solves my problem!! thanks all !!!