# No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response (com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I have tried to upload a file to my Jave RESTful webservice but this failed.

I get the following Error Message:

```
 [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public
 javax.ws.rs.core.Response
 com.example.rest.jersey.businesscard.BusinessCardService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition)
 at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST,
 consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[],
 suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS,
 invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class
 com.example.rest.jersey.businesscard.BusinessCardService,
 handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@6dd319f2]},
 definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
 com.example.rest.jersey.businesscard.BusinessCardService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition),
 parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file,
 defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class
 com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file,
 defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response},
 nameBindings=[]}']
```

The following is my code:

This is the Java class:

```
@POST
   @Path("/upload")
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   public Response uploadFile(
       @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
       @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

       String uploadedFileLocation = "C:\\Users\\Desktop"  + fileDetail.getFileName();

      //save it
       writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

       String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

       return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

   }

  //save uploaded file to new location
   private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
       String uploadedFileLocation) {

       try {
           OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                   uploadedFileLocation));
           int read = 0;
           byte[]bytes = new byte[1024];

           out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
           while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
               out.write(bytes, 0, read);
           }
           out.flush();
           out.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "upload"> Choose file to upload<br>
<form action="rest/businessCards/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" id="filename" type="file" /><br><br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</div>
```

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.vogella.jersey.todo</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.rest.jersey.businesscard</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
     <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>5</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have tried to use the following code to import:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;
```

But when I do this, I get this error:

```
The import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart cannot be resolved
```

I have tried to added following code to my web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

but then I get this error:

```
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.example.rest.jersey.businesscard.BusinessCardService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.example.rest.jersey.businesscard.BusinessCardService, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@404e87f4]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.example.rest.jersey.businesscard.BusinessCardService.uploadFile(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
```

I tried everything I could thought of.

Comment: Do you have 

JAX-RS dependency in your pom?
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I don´t use Maven. So I haven´t a pom

Comment: You're using the wrong Jersey version of the multipart classes. Get rid of jersey-multipart dependency and let auto-imports of your IDE kick in. They will be the same classes with different packaging. `org.glassfish.jersey`, not `com.sun.jersey`. This is in regards to the `FormDataContentDisposition` and `FormDataParam`

Comment: My IDE wants to auto-importcom.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam; and import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

Comment: That's why I said to remove the jersey-multipart dependency. That's where those classes are coming from. That is for Jersey 1.x. Jersey 2.x, you use jersey-media-multipart

Comment: Excuse me, I don´t understand what you mean. What should I remove? And what should I write instead? My IDE wants to include com.sun.jeresy.multipart (but then it don´t work; error in the question) and you said I should add org.glassdisch.jersey.multipart but then I get an error ( I described it in my question, at the end)

Comment: Remove the dependency from your project. The `jersey-multipart` dependency is for Jersey 1.x. You can see in the error message the package name of the class starts with `com.sun.jersey`. That is Jersey 1.x. You need to get rid of it. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653012/multipart-form-data-no-injection-source-found-for-a-parameter-of-type-public-ja/30656345#30656345). It's pretty much duplicate question of yours.