# Jersey @FormDataParam returns wrong String

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to create a Post function in my REST API with the @FormDataParam annotation. However, when I try to test it with Postman the String that gets returned is very strange.

This is my method:

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response createBrand(@FormDataParam("name") String name){
        brandDAO.create(new Brand(name));
        return Response
                .ok("Name of brand = " + name)
                .build();
    }
```

Say I have the settings `key = name` and `value="test"`. I would expect that `name` would be set to test, but it is actually set to:

```
----------------------------371301867522909150048733\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"name\"; filename=\"\"\r\n\r\n\r\n----------------------------371301867522909150048733--\r\n
```

Have I misunderstood how to actually get the value from the form data, or am I using the method wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jersey 2, make sure you have [registered the MultiPartFeature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435). If you don't the `@FormDataParam` annotation will be ignored and it will be treated like the String is the entire entity, which is what looks like it going on.