# File Wrong Upload Jersey RestFull Service

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey

I really can't understand the reason for this error.
I ran the sample application. It works correctly. Same code but cannot load correctly. I think the error is due to the version difference. Anyone have any suggestions for a solution?

The web service I created

```
    @POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getImageText( @FormDataParam("file")InputStream inputStream) { 
        try {
            byte[] bytes =IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);             
            inputStream.close();                
            System.out.println(bytes.length);           
             ArrayList<ImageBarcod> temp=null;
            return Response.ok(temp).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response
                    .status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                    .build();               
        }   
}
```

bytes.length output:

[image]

file size to upload

[image]

[sample application](https://javatutorial.net/java-file-upload-rest-service)

[image]

upload file:

[image: upload file]

save file:

[image: save file]

Libraries:

[image: Maven Libraries]

Comment: _"I really can't understand the reason for this error"_ - What error? Please be specific.

Comment: I am sending the file from the client to the server, the expected file size is 190906. But the incoming file size is 191169

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the InputStream to compare its contents?

Comment: I have updated the question now. I guess I need to pull the body part

Comment: What you are seeing is the _entire_ raw multipart request. What you want is just the extracted 'file' part. Normally, this is wha the `@FormDataParam` does; it extracts the part that you specify in the annotation. What this tells me is that the annotation is not being recognized, and so the InputStream is simply the entire request entity. My guess is that the `@FormDataParam` annotation you are using is not the correct one (maybe different package - version 2.x). It is hard to tell without more information. I suggest you post all your dependencies and app configuration if you want more help

Comment: I edited the question. You can see the photo of the Libraries. There must be a missing .jar file. @RequestBody does not appear.

Comment: Please stop using screenshots when using text is possible. It is much easier to view your pom dependencies than to look at a picture of jars. Same goes with all your other screenshots.

Comment: Also @RequestBody is for Spring MVC. You are not using Spring MVC. Also why do have both Jersey 1.x and 2.x dependencies? You know that the two are incompatible, right? I don't even know which one you are using for your project. Where is your web.xml?

Comment: Multipart version: When I deleted 1.8 and got 2.25, it was fixed. I removed all 1.x versions. I'm sorry I took your time. Thank you for giving a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Jersey 2.x, but your Multipart dependency is for Jersey 1.x. The two Jersey versions are incompatible. So the `@FormDataParam` annotation you using is just being ignored. That's why what you are getting in the `InputStream` is the entire multipart entity instead of just the file part.

What you need to do is get rid of all your Jersey 1.x dependencies then add the Jersey 2.x `jersey-media-multipart` dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you need to register the `MultiPartFeature` with your application. You can see a few different ways to do that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656345/2587435). After you do that, you will be able to use the 2.x version of the `@FormDataParam` (which is different from the 1.x version).