# Getting object from @PathParam

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'm creating a RESTful service for accessing data.

So I started writing that service, first I created a `ReadOnlyResource` interface with the following code:

```
public interface ReadOnlyResource<E, K> {
    Collection<E> getAll();
    E getById(K id);
}
```

Where E is the returned type and K is the key element.

So if I'm implementing with `<Integer, Integer>` I'll inject the key like t

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Override
public Integer getById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return null;
}
```

But when my key is more complex, like this:

```
public class ComplexKey {
    private String name;
    private int value;
}
```

How can I inject this so I can use my interface?

Is there a way to inject both params and create the key with them?

EDIT: the solution of @QueryParam doesn't help because what I try to reach is going to /*some name*/*some number* and receive a ComplexKey instance which contains the some name and some number values from the url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing custom type query parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403033/passing-custom-type-query-parameter)

Comment: Not exactly, when I wanted is a way that I can implement it with my current interface, the <K> must be 1 argument passed to the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what I try to reach is going to */some name/some number* and receive a ComplexKey instance which contains the some name and some number values from the url

Use a [`@BeanParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html)

```
public class ComplexKey {
    @PathParam("name")
    private String name;
    @PathParam("value")
    private int value;
    // getters/setters
}

@Path("/{name}/{value}")
getById(@BeanParam ComplexKey key)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can have Objects as `@PathParam`, if you have a Constructor that i.e. parses a String, like:

```java
public class ComplexKey {
    private String name;
    private int value;
    
    public ComplexKey(String stringValue) {
        // parse the stringValue and assign name and value
    }
}
```

Or as an Alternative, you can use a static method `fromString` for the conversion:

`public static ComplexKey fromString(stringValue) {…}`

```java
@GET
@Path("/{complexId}")
@Override
public Integer getById(@PathParam("complexId") ComplexId complexId) {
    return null;
}
```

The call then could look like:
`http://localhost:8080/api/John-25`